# Property getting shared between instances of ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

I have a model `Call` that gets assigned to an ObjectController called `CallController`. This controller has a property `links: []` and an `init()` function that populates this `links` property based on the `Call` model properties. My template looks something like this, simplified:

```
{{#each calls itemController="call"}}
    {{callerId}}
    {{#each links itemController="link}}
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the `links` attribute is behaving as though it is shared between all instances of `CallController`. If I have two different calls, then the data added to `links` in the `init()` methods appear under each call.

I seem to recall hearing that controllers are not initialized for each new model, rather they are reused. Perhaps this is the problem? What is a workaround?

Comment: What you write is true. Couldn't you just initialize this links property directly on the model?

Comment: You're right about the reuse; the container treats all controllers as singletons by default. I've never used the `itemController` property though, so I don't know how that affects controller creation.

Comment: @Myslik That's what I'm doing right now. It *feels* wrong though, as I'm using Ember Data to initially populate the model.

Comment: And do you need the controller to do the initialization? Because I do not see why having some computed property on Ember Data Model is bad.

Comment: @Myslik that's not too bad of an idea. I spend most of my time in Rails and we try to keep the ORM as clean as possible and have all logic outside of it. Maybe it makes sense to just include it in the model here. I'm assuming it's ok to have a model attribute that returns a promise?

Comment: So you mean you are making some AJAX call in it? That is probably not so clean. Do you have any detail on your use case?

Comment: I'm loading phone call records via Ember Data. Once I have the phone number for each record, I'm making a call to a search function in a JS library that has a callback function for the results. The JS library is a salesforce library, so I'm loading associated records from it (an alternate datasource than what Ember Data is using). I'm currently wrapping the Salesforce library calls in a promise object.